# What's the difference between GHC's -c and -no-link options?

Tags: haskell, linker, ghc

The help says:

```
 -c  Do not link
```

and

```
 -no-link  Omit linking
```

I understand that `-c` prevents the linking part completely. But what's the difference if I specify `-no-link`? Does the linking phase actually do something apart from linking?

**Update:** Interestingly, `-no-link` is [deprecated in GHC 6.12, but undeprecated in GHC 7](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1220).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAK `-c` doesn't handle dependencies. E.g.

Main.hs:

```
module Main
where

import Test

main :: IO ()
main = test
```

Test.hs:

```
module Test
where

test :: IO ()
test = print 123
```

Trying to compile with `-c`:

```
$ ghc -c Main.hs

Main.hs:5:1:
    Failed to load interface for `Test'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

With `-no-link`:

```
$ ghc -no-link Main.hs
[1 of 2] Compiling Test             ( Test.hs, Test.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
```